# Error on loading image when testing on iPhone 5

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I'm trying to set the image on a TableCell.

This is my code:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellIdentifier);
    Parking parking = (tableItems.ToArray () [indexPath.Row] as Parking);

    if (cell == null) {
        cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, cellIdentifier);
    }

    cell.TextLabel.Text = parking.Name;

    UIImage img = UIImage.FromBundle ("occupied");
    cell.ImageView.Image = img;

    cell.DetailTextLabel.Text = parking.GenerateSubtitle ();
    cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}
```

This works perfect while testing on an emulator, but when I try to debug this on my iPhone 5, I get this error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIImage.FromBundle (System.String name) [0x0001e] in         /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIImage.g.cs:198
  at parko_iphone.MainTableSource.GetCell (MonoTouch.UIKit.UITableView tableView,     MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath) [0x0004c] in /Users/gertpoppe/projects/parko_iphone/parko_iphone/CustomComponents/MainTableSource.cs:34
  at at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging:void_objc_msgSend (intptr,intptr)
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIWindow.MakeKeyAndVisible () [0x00008] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIWindow.g.cs:129
  at parko_iphone.AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching (MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication app, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSDictionary options) [0x0002e] in /Users/gertpoppe/projects/parko_iphone/parko_iphone/AppDelegate.cs:35
  at at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0004c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:38
  at parko_iphone.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00008] in /Users/gertpoppe/projects/parko_iphone/parko_iphone/Main.cs:16
```

The error happens on the line where I load the image:

```
UIImage img = UIImage.FromBundle ("occupied");
```

Comment: Is 'occupied' the right casing? The iOS simulator is case-insensitive, while devices are case-sensitive.

Comment: The name off the image is "occupied.png" and "occupied@2x.png", so I don't think that's the problem

Comment: Try adding an image extension to the name of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
UIImage img = UIImage.FromBundle ("occupied");
```

With:

```
UIImage *img = UIImage.FromBundle ("occupied");
```

OR

Try replacing:

```
UIImage img = UIImage.FromBundle ("occupied");
cell.ImageView.Image = img;
```

With:

```
cell.ImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"occupied"]];
```

Comment: gert789 uses C# (and not Objective C) to create the app. So the proposed code won't work.